# "no surround templates defined in this context" in WebStorm when Ctrl+Alt+J after selecting a text

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

In WebStorm in html file I select a text and do <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + J</kbd> and get "no surround templates defined in this context".

What do I wrong in it?

```
<i class="link to-be-copied">$SELECTION$</i>
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me in a plain HTML file -- https://i.imgur.com/PTA56eA.png. 1) Please show how IDE looks when you invoke it (as it **should have** more than 1 entry for surround template (at very least bundled ones for link, tag and Emmet). Show whole IDE window, including the editor tab and ideally that file visible (selected) the in the Project View panel as well -- want to see what icon it has;

Comment: 2) Locate that file in the Project View panel, focus it and invoke shortcut for `View | Quick Documentation` (`Ctrl+Q` here on Windows) -- show the popup / need to see what IDE thinks about the file. 3) Please disable any custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart IDE and try again -- any difference? Some plugins can "steal" or mess up with the file type so it's no longer proper "HTML" context but something else / screws up certain IDE functionality, especially Emmet/Live templates based.

Comment: Change Applicable to "EveryWhere" works for me